# PHP basic echo if $post exist

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo

I am new to PHP and am using php to mysql query some data for internal use though a checkbox form, using HTML checkboxes with $POST
my variables will be things like datetime, varchar, integer. For example, the user could check the columns 'date', 'user_id', 'username', 'revenue'

User can select column names, and I need the output to be thrown into a html table

User can select one, or all column names, so resulting echo must be able to adapt.

I can use isset($_POST['email_address']) in the mysql query to choose the columns without having issues if the checkbox isn't checked, but now sure how to generate the echo without duplicate html tags.

I would use

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlResult)) {
    echo "'<td>'{isset($_POST['email_address'])}'</td><td>'{isset($_POST['username'])}'</td>'" ;    
}
```

but then I would have empty columns.

I need to have only the selected columns in my resulting table. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: you cannot run php code inside a string. e.g. `echo "print('x')"` is not going to execute the print statement, whether you surround it with `{}` or not. you'll just be printing out `p`, `r`, `i`, etc...

Comment: Please, don't write new applications using `mysql_query`. It's a deprecated interface and it will be removed in future versions of PHP. [Updating to PDO is not hard](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move the tags into `if()` statements:

```
if(isset($_POST['email_address']))
{
    echo "<td>$_POST['email_address']</td>";
}
if(//...)
{
    //...
}
//...
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking form just wasn't sure how to write it

Answer (score 2):

PHP won't interpolate expressions only simple variables, you have to concatenate your output.

What you are probably after is

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlResult)) {
    echo "<td>".(isset($_POST['email_address'])?$_POST["email_address"]:"No Email")."</td>".
         "<td>".(isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST["username"]:"No Username")."</td>" ;    
}
```

or to nix the fields you could just calculate how may fields you are missing and use str_repeat

```
$numFields = (isset($_POST['email_address'])?1:0) +
             (isset($_POST['email_address'])?1:0);

echo str_repeat("<td></td>", $numFields);
```

Comment: he does not need empty columns m8

Comment: I needed the if( solution, not blank/static value columns

Answer (score 1):

This way your column cell will only appear if your post variables have been set.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlResult)) {
    if (isset($_POST['email_address'])) {
        echo '<td>'.$_POST['email_address'].'</td>';
        }
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        echo '<td>'.$_POST['username'].'</td>';
        }
    }
```